# Using a compass css3 mixin for a padding transition

Tags: css, css-transitions, compass

I'm trying to avoid the use of vendor prefixes by using a compass css3 mixin:

```
-webkit-transition: padding 500ms ease;
-moz-transition: padding 500ms ease;
-ms-transition: padding 500ms ease;
-o-transition: padding 500ms ease;
transition: padding 500ms ease;
```

The compass css3 equivalent would be something similar to:

```
@include transition(padding, 500ms, ease, 0);
```

or

```
@include transition(padding 500ms ease);
```

However, that isn't working. What would be the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
@include transition(padding 500ms ease);
```

Comment: This also isn't working. Updated the query with this addition. I'm wondering if the combination of transition and padding is possible using the compass css3 mixin.

Comment: Have you imported `@import "compass/css3"`?

Comment: Yes. It's also not something else that's conflicting I think because if I fully write out the vendor prefixes it works. The version of my Compass 1.0.3 (Polaris) by the way.

Comment: Have you checked the compiled css? Or isn't it compiled?